# Error trying to install python pywinpty>=1.1.0 package

Tags: python-3.x, rust, jupyter-notebook, boto3, rust-cargo

I try to install the python for aws glue connectivity,
so I installed pip install --upgrade jupyter boto3 aws-glue-sessions.
I'm getting errors in this particular package.

```
Collecting pywinpty>=1.1.0   Using cached pywinpty-2.0.5.tar.gz (23 kB)   Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [6 lines of output]
     
      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
     
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Comment: So you probably must have Rust installed? https://rustup.rs/

Answer (score 1):

Found a [solution online](https://github.com/ijl/orjson/issues/192#issuecomment-1087757020). Installing 64 bit Python resolved my issue. Check your installation with `python -V -V`, it should say 64 bit.